# Vaadin 8: Widgetset not compiling com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.DefaultWidgetSet not found in project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gwt, vaadin

I am trying to implement a Vaadin 8 framework project (8.0.5) but I can't get the widgetset to compile.

Using Glassfish 4 (alternatively, tried on Wildfly) DB: ObjectDB. I do have the charts and Timeline addon (Licensed). Theme compiles fine, using eclipse Vaadin plugin. WAR deploys fine.

After bringing up glassfish, tried accessing the UI - `MyAppWidgetset.nocache.js not found` error.

At this point tried compiling the widgetset Build failure with error `com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.DefaultWidgetSet not found` in project.

`pom.xml` reflects the same error at `<execution>` element.

Tried the fowllowing:

Added: `@WidgetSet` annotation to the `MainUI` class. Then added a `gwt.xml` class in `../resources/{package-folder structure}` found on Vaadin forum:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 1.7.0//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.7.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module>     
    <inherits name="com.vaadin.addon.charts.Widgetset" />
    <inherits name="com.vaadin.addon.timeline.gwt.TimelineWidgetSet" />
    <inherits name="com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet" />     
</module>
```

I manually tried adding:

```
<inherits name="com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.DefaultWidgetSet" />
```

But as soon as I save, Eclipse editor deletes that row. Is that supposed to happen? Tried adding from an external editor, but it gets deleted as soon as I open it in Eclipse.

After selectivly adding dependencies, the problem seems to be with charts.
Apparently, Adding Vaadin Charts dependency is causing the compilation to fail.
But I do have the license key in my root folder.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin.addon</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-charts</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Most likely duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42965056/build-fails-after-upgrading-from-vaadin-7-8), and most likely you're using some add-ons which do not support V8, or you've not updated to the version which is compatible with 8.

Comment: Yes, it is on very similar lines. The root cause is the same but the error reported is different. Quite possibly, due to versions evolution. And thank you for your comment. It worked.

Answer (score 3):

So I was doing 2 things wrong:

1. The location of the license file. A per the Demo code on github, it was in the root folder of the project. It has to be under \Users\(username) Directory.
2. Vaadin 8 works with Charts 4.0 and not earlier versions.